# Setting up @username, First and Last names using telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

How can I change **username**, **FirstName**, **LastName** with help of telethon? I only found the method for enabling 2F verification `client.edit_2fa(new_password='12345')`. Is there something similar to change username, Firstname and LastName.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Telethon library provides full access to the Telegram API. You can scan official documentation and find necessary method. There are two places where you can get an answer:

- [Accessing the Full API](http://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/advanced-usage/accessing-the-full-api.html)
- [account.updateProfile](https://core.telegram.org/method/account.updateProfile) method

Then you can check [Telethon API helper site](https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/methods/account/update_profile.html) which will give you desired python method

```
from telethon.tl.functions.account import UpdateProfileRequest
```